# Set product quantities to 0 in Odoo 10

Tags: odoo, odoo-9, odoo-10

We are ready to deploy our instance to production and I'm currently cleaning all the demo data made during the process.

I usually follow this steps to clean major sample data:

*SSH into server*

```
su postgres
psql abc_db_name

delete from stock_pack_operation;
delete from stock_picking;
delete from stock_move;
delete from account_invoice;
delete from account_partial_reconcile;
delete from account_move;
delete from sale_order;
delete from account_payment;
```

**The main problem I'm facing now is set all the product quantities to 0 without deleting the products.** What's the query I need to run to set this to reset them and start the inventory from scratch?

Comment: I do not recommend you to delete data like this. Instead of this you should keep a database without data and if you want to make some tests you can do it with other different database

Comment: I think he needs the list of the products

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try:

```
UPDATE stock_quant SET qty=0;
```

Answer (score 2):

The quantity of the product are in model :

```
   stock.quant
```

just delete those record and the product should be Zero.

try this:

```
   delete from stock_quant;
```

because odoo change the name of the model to valid postgres name
by changing the . to _

Comment: Can you please type the exact command? It will help me a lot! Thanks

Comment: Thank for your commands always think about writing them but i'm to lazy ^^.